# How to insert the result of mysql stored procedure in shell script

Tags: mysql, bash, shell, stored-procedures

I'm new to shell script and I want to call the MySQL stored procedure and stored the result of the stored procedure in a variable and pass the variable to insert query to store the values in another table with data type JSON.

**Shell Script File:**

```
selectvar="CALL lead_status_sale(input1,input2,@total,@valid,@data);"

selectvar1="select @total,@valid,@data;"

mysql --user=root --password=xxx db1 << eof 
$selectvar
insertvar = $selectvar1
eof

mysql --user=root --password=xxx db2 << eof 
insert into day values $insertvar;
eof
```

If I call the Stored Procedure its working fine when i go for insert query I got ERROR

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@valid @qualified  @sales  @closedwon  @deal   @cold_lead  @business   @ga @ga_valid   @ga' at line 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
If your SELECT return more than 1 string:

```
#!/bin/bash

selectvar="CALL lead_status_sale(input1,input2,@total,@valid,@data); select @total,@valid,@data;"
insertvar=(`mysql --user=root --password=xxx db1 --execute="${selectvar}" | sed '1d'`)
for i in "${insertvar[@]}"
do
    mysql --user=root --password=xxx db2 --execute="insert into day values ${i};"
done
```

Comment: I got some error ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: Is there any possibility of special character problem in the result of stored procedure @Viktor Khilin

Comment: @Sarath i've read your question inattentively first. Edited my solution, try this. If it still shows and arrow, let me see `bash -x this_script_name.sh` output

Comment: problem in the insert query do no how to solve this, I tried but this the error now showing ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL ' at line 1
@Viktor Khilin

Comment: everything working fine but the problem in the insert statement. ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1213 1174 367 57 8 7398 39 678 11 11 8 7 0 0 9 5 5 3 3 00 5 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 15 15' at line 1 @Viktor Khilin

Comment: We are close :) Once more edit, check please @Sarath

Comment: Your last edit made work for me. Problem is in insert query eg: values('$i') its working. But I got one more problem it stores every row but I want to store like JSON or array kind of data. Thanks a lot